# Changing Flash player of Firefox cache

Tags: windows-7, firefox, flash-player, browser-cache

I want to relocate the Flash player plugin of Firefox cache so that it saves my C: drive space when I watch youtube videos. I successfully changed the firefox cache by opening about:config and then created a new string key "browser.cache.disk.parent_directory" where I put the value of the new cache location. But it doesn't work with online streaming contents such as youtube videos.

Please guide me *where does it get stored* and how to **change its cache into another drive**.

Comment: You didn't specify the operating system but assuming Windows you may wish to read about [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) and [junction points.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point)

Comment: Yes I am sorry, I should have mentioned it, but you are right its windows 7 32bit

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from reading the documentation on changing your Flash settings and the related control panel, you can't change its location. A comment on at the end of the [How do I clear my Flash Player cache and settings?](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4278569#4278569) question in the Flash Player FAQs says this:

> You can also manually accomplish this task by deleting the contents of
>   the following folders:
>
> Windows (tip: copy and paste these paths into the path bar in an
>   Explorer window)
>
> ```
> %appdata%\Adobe\Flash Player
> %appdata%\Macromedia\Flash Player
> ```
>
> Macintosh
>
> ```
> ~\Library\Preferences\Macromedia\Flash Player\
> ~\Library\Caches\Adobe\Flash Player\
> ```